# Word for entity baskets?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that is parent to "entity" and not on lines of "kind" or "all entities"?

Example: I have three "kinds" of entities, "forum", "topic", and "post".

I store them in a large area called "entities" as well which is confusing the heck out of me. I needed a different name.

```
entities: <<<<<<<< I need a better word here
    forumEntities:  entity1, entity2, entity3,
    topicsEntities: entity1, entity2, entity3,
    postsEntities:  entity1, entity2, entity3
```

So really the word I'm looking for is something to mean "all entity groups" or "various entity groups" or "entity baskets" or "entity branch".

I was thinking maybe worst case change the word entity to "stuff" then be like "stuffings > (stuffing === stuffs) > stuff"

```
stuffings:
    forumStuffs: stuff1, stuff2, stuff3
    topicStuffs: stuff1, stuff2, stuff3
    postStuffs:  stuff1, stuff2, stuff3
```

If you have any ideas better then "stuff" i'm all for abandoning the word "entity". Here is another I thought of, "entita" which is not a real word, I go the idea from the animal kingdom, phyla, phylum etc:

```
entitas:
    formEntita == forumEntitys: entity1, entity2, entity3
```

Comment: 'Items' might do it for you.

Comment: Thanks @NigelJ but I didn't like that, I tired. Do you have any ideas along "stuff"?

Comment: "forum", "topic" and "post" are all types of blogEntry?

Comment: @RupertMorrish it was just a made up example. Thanks though.

Comment: Ah. In that case, how about "entityCollection"? Of if you want something more abstract, an "aggregate"?

Comment: Even if yours were a Question about English, why on Earth would you use *a made-up example* please?

If you can find a way to force this into an English Question, please post the real problem

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin a better word choice would be "i picked an example". I actually use entity > entitys in a lot of different places. One of them happens to be a forum style.

Comment: Thanks @RupertMorrish I think I'm going to do `entitas > entita === entitys > entity`. I got the idea from the animal kingdom, phyla, and organisms haha.

Comment: [Category](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/category) sounds like the correct word to me.

Comment: What about an entourage of entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer so it stops showing up in the "Unanswered" queue. The correct answer is above in the comments:

> Thanks @RupertMorrish I think I'm going to do entitas > entita === entitys > entity. I got the idea from the animal kingdom, phyla, and organisms haha. – Noitidart Nov 3 at 7:45